# What is the difference between single and double layer potential

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, potential-theory

I want to know the difference between **single layer** and **double layer**  potentials. Is there a  link between the choice of   single/double  layer  potential  and the  boundary  condition  of a PDE or an homogeneity?

Comment: A double layer can be obtained through a limiting process upon considering two single layers.... but it is not clear to me, what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 5):

Single layer potential is continuous on the boundary, but its normal derivative jumps by a specified amount as we cross the boundary. This property can be used to solve the Neumann problem (prescribed normal derivative on the boundary).

Double layer potential is itself discontinuous on the boundary, its value jumps by a specified amount as we cross the boundary. This property can be used to solve the Dirichlet problem (prescribed boundary values).

The passage from the jump properties to the solution of boundary problem takes some work. This topic is discussed in much detail on Wikipedia: [Neumann–Poincaré operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann%E2%80%93Poincar%C3%A9_operator#Single_layer_potentials) and on EoM: [Potential theory](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Potential_theory).

Comment: Can you give me Reference in which I find your reasoning. but in some document I found that, we can use the simple layer potential for the Neumann condition (eg J. Nedelec C in this [link](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/M2AN/M2AN_1973__7_3/M2AN_1973__7_3_105_0/M2AN_1973__7_3_105_0.pdf)